# No parentheses in java

Tags: java, parentheses

I am learning Java and I have learned that methods use parentheses for passing parameters. However, I have also noticed that sometimes I see code which to me looks like a method but it does not have parentheses.

```
MyObject.something()

MyObject.somethingElse
```

Where somethingElse does not have parentheses. I assume this is similar to how an arrayList has the size method for getting its size:

```
myList.size()
```

whereas an array has length to get its size, which does not have parentheses:

```
myArray.length
```

**Is my assumption correct? If not, what is the difference?**
This is probably an elementary question, but because of the amount of words I need to explain this problem, I have had trouble searching for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`somethingElse` is a *property* (data member), not a method. No code in the class is run when you access that member, unlike with a method where code in the class is run.

Here's an example:

```
public class Foo {

    public int bar;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = 42;
    }

    public int getBlarg() {
        // code here runs when you call this method
        return 67;
    }

}
```

If you create a `Foo` object:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

...you can access the *property* `bar` without parens:

```
System.out.println(f.bar);        // "42"
```

...and you can **call** the method `getBlarg` using parens:

```
System.out.println(f.getBlarg()); // "67"
```

When you call `getBlarg`, the code in the `getBlarg` method runs. This is fundamentally different from accessing the data member `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

`myList.size()` call a method defined in list class (public defined)

`myArray.length` call a property in array class not method

```
public class MyClass{

    public int length;

    public int size(){
    ....
    }
}

MyClass mc =new MyClass();
mc.length;
mc.size();
```

Answer (score 3):

it is a class field which isn't a `private` field (usually it can be `protected`,`package` or `public`), so you can take it straight from your class. Usually fields are private, so you cannot take it like this outside your class definition.

Comment: +1 for using the correct term - "field", as opposed to the incorrect term - "property", like some other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is triggering method called something of the instantiated object called someObject.

```
someObject.something();
```

This is accessing a property of the object called someObject (property which is public, most probably).

```
someObject.name
```

Comment: It can be packaged or protected